# Управление планом электропитания средствами c#

Tags: c#, windows

Здравствуйте, появилась задумка как охладить свой ноутбук в простое. Нужно средствами c# мониторить процентную загрузку центрального процессора и изменять частоту процессора в зависимости от загрузки. Допустим если загрузка 20% ставить частоту 2.5 ГГц, если процессор не будет справляться и загрузка будет 90-100% то ставить частоту 3.5 ГГц. Как я думаю самый простой способ это менять максимальную частоту в настройке плана электропитания ноутбука. Но я не найду как это можно изменить, в стандартных возможностях c# не нашёл, пытался найти запись в реестре но тоже безуспешно. Подскажите может кто уже сталкивался с таким.

Comment: Эта функция уже встроена в современные процессоры и не требует написания доп.софта

Comment: Вам не кажется, что Вы только что попытались изобрести велосипед?

Comment: @Bulson Если бы эта функция была встроена в процессор то мой core-7 6700HQ в простое ноутбука не работал бы на 3.2 ггц и не нагревал так ноутбук, ради эксперимента я поставил в настройке плана электропитания максимальную частоту 2ГГц и при этом каких либо лагов не заметил но температура снизилась значительно.

Comment: @Dejsving Уважаемый, я ставлю конкретный вопрос (собственно для чего и придумали этот сайт) и жду простого ответа, я не спрашиваю имеет ли смысл это делать так как я уже решил что имеет, я просто пытаюсь получить информацию у более опытных людей и всё. Поправьте меня если я не прав.

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/company/intel/blog/155261/ и проверьте настройки BIOS в своем ноутбуке

Comment: @Lorem Так как у Вас ноут, и процессор далеко не старый, то у Вас должна эта функция не только быть, но и от производителя ноута стоять программа, которая как раз этим и занимается. Именно поэтому, я вам сказал, что Вы изобретаете велосипед. Если же у Вас желание написать программу именно самому в качестве практики и расширения кругозора, тогда извините.

Comment: Может вам поискать datasheet на северный мост, или на процессор... Возможно там что-то есть полезное.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно попробовать PO_THROTTLE_DEGRADE у функции WriteProcessorPwrScheme. (WinApi)

Или

WMI/Win32_Processor/SetPowerState

Но это проще вручную выставить

Power Plan/Change advanced Power Settings/
Processor Power Management/
Maximum Processor Frequency

Windows уже понижает автоматически частоту CPU на всех процессорах которые умеют понижать частоту при снижении нагрузки. Собственно ничего не надо писать.